# Sumar y restar valores al esconder o mostrar un div

Tags: php, javascript

quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar, orientar a solucionar este problema, tengo un valor bruto y a partir de esto puedo sumar o restar valores, dependiendo de la selección que haga, me explico, yo vengo con un valor bruto de 500000, aqui puedo seleccionar si por el combobox si tengo becas, si poseo beca debo agregar el monto que se sumará al total, y lo mismo para aportes extras, si selecciono si debo agregar el monto que se sumará al total, creo que eso lo hace, pero mi problema es que si yo vuelvo a ocultar cualquiera de los div anteriores no me realiza la resta y no se en que estoy fallando, aqui dejo mi código para ver si me pueden ayudar:

Javascript:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function Suma(name){
    param=document.getElementById('ingreso').value;
    param1=document.getElementById('monto_aporte').value;

    if($('#aporteNo').is(':checked')){
        document.getElementById('total').value=eval(param);
    }else{
        document.getElementById('total').value=eval(param)+eval(param1);
    }
}

function Resta(name){
    param=document.getElementById('ingreso').value;
    param1=document.getElementById('monto_aporte').value;

    document.getElementById('total').value=eval(param);
}

function SumaS(name){
    param=document.getElementById('ingreso').value;
    param2=document.getElementById('monto_s').value;

    if($('#sNo').is(':selected')){
        document.getElementById('total').value=eval(param);
    }else{
        document.getElementById('total').value=eval(param)+eval(param2);
    }
}

function RestaS(name){
    param=document.getElementById('ingreso').value;
    param2=document.getElementById('monto_s').value;

    document.getElementById('total').value=eval(param);
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('input[name=aporte]').click(function (){
        if($(this).val()==1){
            $("#monto").fadeIn();
        }else{
            $("#monto").fadeOut();
        }
    });

});

function mostrar(id) {
    if (id!=8) {
        $("#montoS").show();
    }
    if (id==0 || id==8) {
        $("#montoS").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table width="534" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
              <td width="137" class="label">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="182">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="195" class="ejemplos">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

              <td height="36" class="label">Total Liquido</td>
              <td>
                <input name="ingreso" type="text" id="ingreso" value="500000" onchange="javascript:Suma();"  onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
              </td>
              <td class="txtAdvertencia">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 
           <tr>
              <td class="txtBoldNormal">Tienes beca</td>
              <td>
                  <select name="ts" id="ts" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
                    <option value="0">--</option>
                    <option value="8"  id="sSi" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="8") { echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:RestaS();">Ninguno</option>
                    <option value="9"  id="sNo" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="9") { echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:SumaS();">1</option>
                    <option value="10" id="sNo" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="10"){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:SumaS();">2</option>
                    <option value="11" id="sNo" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="11"){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:SumaS();">3  ó más</option>
                  </select>
                  </td>
              <td >&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="montoS" style="display:<?PHP echo ($pdata['ts']==9 || $pdata['ts']==10 || $pdata['ts']==11)?"checked=\"block\"":"none";?>">
              <td height="36" class="label">Monto</td>
              <td><input id="monto_s" name="monto_s" type="text" value="<?php if($pdata['monto_s']!=""){echo $pdata['monto_s'];}else{echo "0";};?>" onchange="javascript:SumaS();" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
             </td>
              <td class="txtAdvertencia">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="txtBoldNormal">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="txtAdvertencia">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="35" class="label">Aportes Extras</td>
              <td  class="label">
                <input type="radio" name="aporte" id="aporteSi" value="1" <?php if($pdata['aporte']=="1"){ echo "checked";}?> onclick="javascript:Suma();"/>Si
                <input type="radio" name="aporte" id="aporteNo" value="0" <?php if($pdata['aporte']=="0"){ echo "checked";}?> onclick="javascript:Resta();"/>No
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="txtBoldNormal">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="txtAdvertencia">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="monto" style="display:<?PHP echo ($pdata['aporte']==1)?"checked=\"block\"":"none";?>">
              <td height="36" class="label">Monto Aporte</td>
              <td><input id="monto_aporte" name="monto_aporte" type="text"  value="<?php if($pdata['monto_aporte']!=""){echo $pdata['monto_aporte'];}else{echo "0";};?>" onchange="javascript:Suma();" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
             </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="label">INGRESOS TOTALES (ingresos)</td>
              <td><span>
                <input name="total" type="text" id="total" value="<?php if($pdata['total']!=""){echo $pdata['total'];}else{echo "0";};?>" onchange="javascript:Suma();SumaS();" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
              </span></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Y antes de cerrar el body llamo a las funciones en bloque js:

```
<script>
    Suma();
    SumaS();
</script>
```

Comment: Juanjo , deberías hacer un código de ejemplo más corto, para así ayudarte con tu problema, explicame que necesitas más resumidamente y quisás pueda ayudarte.

Comment: y las funciones `Suma(); ` & `SumaS();` no es necesario ejecutarlas cuando los valores cambien? la verdad no esta muy claro el problema. Pudieras explicar un caso de uso cuando menos.

Comment: la verdad no me queda muy en claro tu problema, tal vez lo que te esta fallando es la logica y no es un problema tecnico. Lo que probablemente tienes que hacer es que cuando cambie la visibilidad de los `div` asignar valor 0 a los campos y hacer de nuevo el calculo

Comment: Y como asigno el valor 0, por que aqui llego a un punto en que muevo algo y deja de funcionarme lo que ya funcionaba...

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro cual es en si tu problema, pero creo que esto te puede ayudar.

Tu combobox esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<select name="ts" id="ts" onChange="mostrar(this.value);">
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option value="8"  id="sSi" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="8") { echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:RestaS();">Ninguno</option>
    <option value="9"  id="sNo" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="9") { echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:SumaS();">1</option>
    <option value="10" id="sNo" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="10"){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:SumaS();">2</option>
    <option value="11" id="sNo" <?php if($pdata['ts']=="11"){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?> onclick="javascript:SumaS();">3  ó más</option>
</select>
```

Tu problema aqui es que tienes un evento `onClick` en cada una de las opciones, esto en si no es necesario. Lo que hay que hacer es dejarle el trabajo al Combobox con el evento `onChange`. Ve el siguiente código **(quite el codigo PHP para que se vea mas claro)**:

```
<select name="ts" id="ts" onChange="TienesBeca(this.value);">
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option value="8">Ninguno</option>
    <option value="9">1</option>
    <option value="10">2</option>
    <option value="11">3  ó más</option>
</select>
```

En el evento `onChange` del combo hemos agregado una nueva función, la cual estará de la siguiente forma:

```
function TienesBeca(tieneBecaValor) {

    switch (tieneBecaValor) {
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
            SumaS();
            $("#montoS").show();
            break;
        case 8:
            RestaS();
        default:
            $("#montoS").hide();
            break;
    }
}
```

Cuando sea 9,10 u 11 se manda llamar la función `SumaS()` y se muestra `#montoS`.
Cuando la opción sea un 8 se manda llamar la función `RestaS()` y se oculta `#montoS`, también se ocultará cuando llegue un valor fuera del switch.